# How to use jQuery script inside vue.js app?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

How to use jQuery script inside vue.js app?

```
var app = new Vue({ 
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        users: [{'my_date': ''}]
    }
});

<div id="app">
    <input class="form-control pickadate" v-model="user.my_date" placeholder="My Date">
</div>
```

I run jQuery script like this but when I add `.pickadate` class to my input it doesn't react and datepicker doesn't appear:

```
$('.pickadate').pickadate({
    max: Date.now(),
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
});
```

Comment: how are you including jquery?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to hook into the lifecycle hooks of Vue (`mounted` and `beforeDestroy`). You can then access the root element of the component with `this.$el`. Here is an example:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input class="form-control pickadate" v-model="user.my_date" placeholder="My Date">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: {
        users: [{'my_date': ''}]
    },
    mounted() {
        $('.pickadate', this.$el).pickadate({
            max: Date.now(),
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
        });
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        // remove pickadate according to its API
    }
};
</script>
```

See the official documentation for Vue's lifecycle hooks: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Answer (score 0):

Similiarly, I need to run customized jQuery extension scripts in Vue component, in order to reuse some very complicated functions (writen in es5). Searched and experimented a lot, at last the following solution saved me:

```
    mounted () {
        const script0 = document.createElement('script')
        script0.setAttribute(
          'src',
          'https://xxx/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'
        )
        script0.async = true
        document.head.appendChild(script0)

        const script1 = document.createElement('script')
        script1.setAttribute(
          'src',
          'https://yyy/jquery.kdzzz.js'
        )
        script1.async = true
        document.head.appendChild(script1)
    },
    methods: {
        methodA () {
          window.$.extfunctionA()   // the extended function is defined in the jquery.kdzzz.js
        ...
        }
    }
```